# Selecting an element with Model.ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to style this div:

```
<div id="standings-@pool.PoolId"></div>
```

How do I select all of those divs with a different `id` at once ?

Comment: Please add more detail. What template are you using? - is the @pool.PoolId variable? If so you can use `[id^=standings-]`

Comment: You have to use JavaScript or JQuery for that.

Comment: assign each div the same class and style the class

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan , worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your id `standings` substring is fixed, you can use css selectors for this like

```
div[id^="standings"]
```

It wii selects all elements with a id attribute containing the word "standings"

***Stack Snippet***

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

div[id^="standings"] {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="standings-@pool.1">1</div>
<div id="standings-@pool.2">2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div id="standings-@pool.4">4</div>
<div id="standings-@pool.5">5</div>
<div id="standings-@pool.6">6</div>
```

Comment: This will match every id attribute that contains "standings", not just the ones that start with it.

Comment: @str Agreed...Actually it depend upon the OPs requirement...Updated!

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt Please do read the comments to a question before answering. This was not only answered by a comment 20 minutes before your answer, it was also a duplicate.